# Matrix majorization when a diagonal matrix is multiplied from right and left

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues, matrix-theory

Let $D_1$ and $D_2$ be two diagonal matrices such that $D_1^2+D_2^2=I$ (identity matrix). Suppose matrix $A$ majorizes matrix $B$. Can we show that matrix $A$ majorizes matrix $D_1 A D_1 + D_2 B D_2$? We also know that the diagonal elements of $A$ and $B$ are all ones and both matrices are PSD.